# Initialization of a Struct with a static Member

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, static-members, initializer-list

If I have a `struct`:

```
struct Vec2{
    double _x;
    double _y;
};
```

I can initialize that like this:

```
Vec2 foo = {13.0, 42.0};
```

But what if I have this `struct`?

```
struct Vec2{
    static const double INVALID;

    double _x;
    double _y;
};
```

## Q. How do I initialize that `struct`?

Comment: Static members are shared by every instance. The code to initialize one instance of the struct does not change.

Comment: Initialise an instance exactly as you would without the static member - that doesn't change its aggregatosity. You'll also need a definition for the static member, `const double Vec2::INVALID = <whatever>;` in a source file.

Comment: [Neil Kirk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2068573/neil-kirk) and [Mike Seymour](http://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour) thanks guys this is exactly what I wanted to know. I don't know if I can accept answers on a question that is marked as a duplicate, but if one of you wants to answer I'll try to accept.